# null pointer exceptions when capture image

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-imageview

My app has null pointer exceptions when it tries to take a picture with the camera.

**On clicked button method**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.capture_btn) {     
        try {
            //use standard intent to capture an image
            Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            //we will handle the returned data in onActivityResult
            startActivityForResult(captureIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE);
        }
        catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){

        }
    }
}
```

**On onActivityResult method**

on the activity result the image is sent to the crop operation to re-size the image

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        //user is returning from capturing an image using the camera
        if(requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE){
            //get the Uri for the captured image
            picUri = data.getData();

            //carry out the crop operation
            performCrop();

        }
        //user is returning from cropping the image
        else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){

            //get the returned data
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            //get the cropped bitmap
            Bitmap thePic = extras.getParcelable("data");
            //retrieve a reference to the ImageView
            ImageView picView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageViewMemberRegistration);
            //display the returned cropped image
            picView.setImageBitmap(thePic); // Line 99
        }
    }
}
```

**performCrop**
This part helps to performs a crop operation , resize the image size and return the new size

```
private void performCrop(){

    try {

        //call the standard crop action intent (the user device may not support it)
        Intent cropIntent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP"); 
            //indicate image type and Uri
        cropIntent.setDataAndType(picUri, "image/*");
            //set crop properties
        cropIntent.putExtra("crop", "true");
            //indicate aspect of desired crop
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
        cropIntent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
            //indicate output X and Y
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputX", 256);
        cropIntent.putExtra("outputY", 256);
            //retrieve data on return
        cropIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);
            //start the activity - we handle returning in onActivityResult
        startActivityForResult(cropIntent, PIC_CROP);


    }
    catch(ActivityNotFoundException anfe){

    }
}
```

**Below is the logcat:**

```
 09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=2, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.mobile.ppp/com.mobile.ppp.RegisterMember}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3020)
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2546)
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     ... 12 more
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at com.mobile.ppp.RegisterMember.onActivityResult(RegisterMember.java:99)
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4108)
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3016)
09-11 17:56:46.194: E/AndroidRuntime(1293):     ... 13 more
```

The line 99 point to this

```
99: picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);
```

Comment: which class is "RegisterMember"?   It's trying to deliver the results of your crop, but has this activity already finished?

Comment: Try to highlight where the lines that are causing the null reference are at in your code. RegisterMember.java:99

Comment: @Martin . i edited the code to show the line 99

Comment: `picView` is `null`. You need to determine why.

Comment: @KalelWade the line 99 [picView.setImageBitmap(thePic);] it is when i want to set the content of the image onto the imageview. that is where i have the null pointer exception

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is rather the picView `thePic` is null

Comment: The most likely reason is because there is no `ImageView` in the current `Activity` with id `R.id.imageViewMemberRegistration`. If you need help troubleshooting your layout, please post the XML file for your activity.

Comment: @Jmocke That might be true, too, but that is another issue entirely. The cause of the current problem is that `picView` is `null`.

Comment: Waouuhhhhhhhhhh @Code-Apprentice your are right , i think i need to rest a bit , since yesterday night coding ...Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely reason is because there is no ImageView in the current Activity with id R.id.imageViewMemberRegistration. If you need help troubleshooting your layout, please post the XML file for your activity.
credit goes to  **Code-Apprentice**