# Result intent failing to send to second activity

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using the android cropping library at [this](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop) github repository.

The following code works correctly when removing the below three lines :

```
Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Edit.class);
 i.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString()); 
startActivity(i);
```

I am trying to send the following result intent to the second activity :

```
 private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) { 
    hideProgress();
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    resultView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
    uri=result.getData(); 
   //result.setData(null);
   Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Edit.class);
   i.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString()); 
   startActivity(i);
 }
```

However, for some reason I am getting the following error :

```
ERROR: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.soundcloud.android.crop.example.MainActivity.handleCrop(MainActivity.java:188) 
line 188 is : i.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString());
```

How can I properly send the result intent to the second activity and avoid triggering this error?

Comment: May be `uri.toString() = null`

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25794773/null-pointer-exceptions-when-capture-image

Comment: uri=result.getData();  return null

Comment: do a null check before passing it as extra as @M D said. It could be null

Comment: it looks like your `Uri` is `null`, please confirm that.

Comment: i checked uri for null  but   getting same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the `uri` is null or not, like this:

```
if(uri != null)
    i.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString());
```

**EDIT:**

> how is it possible to be null?

It is null because the getData() is actually null.

> resultview is smoothly get saved to imageview

Well to answer that you can look at the source code of `Crop.getOutput(result)` [here](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop/blob/97502265ce79f25bb6257492a4f76b158febf725/lib/src/main/java/com/soundcloud/android/crop/Crop.java). From the source code:

```
public static Uri getOutput(Intent result) {
        return result.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
    }
```

So `Crop.getOutput(result)` doesn't get the `Uri` from `getData()`. It gets it using `getParcelableExtra()`. So, change your code to this:

```
private void handleCrop(int resultCode, Intent result) { 
    hideProgress();
 if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
    resultView.setImageURI(Crop.getOutput(result));
    uri=result.getParcelableExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT);
   //result.setData(null);
   Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Edit.class);
   i.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString()); 
   startActivity(i);
 }
```

Comment: yes uri is null ..but how is it posible to be null .... u can see  in above(in question code)code  resultview is smoothly get saved to imageview .... and i just simply want to send same result intent to  second activity.....

Comment: i did same as u said but the Edit Class getting null Uri....

**Edit class code** Uri uri = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("imageUri");

Comment: In Edit class you have to get the imageUri using this line `getIntent().getStringExtra("imageUri")`.

Comment: Thanks Dear for your Time Contribution

Answer (score 0):

Check whether `uri.toString(`) is null like

```
if(uri.toString() != null && !uri.toString().isEmpty())
 i.putExtra("imageUri", uri.toString());
```

before passing the data via `Intent`.

Comment: i did same as u told but same error occured 

**if(uri.toString() != null && !uri.toString().isEmpty())** 
**error : null pointer Exception **

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                         at com.soundcloud.android.crop.example.MainActivity.handleCrop(MainActivity.java:193)

line 193 is:if(uri.toString() != null && !uri.toString().isEmpty())

Comment: @altu See my answer, you need to check for `uri` if it is null or not. Because if the `uri` is null and you invoke `toString()` on it, it will throw a `NullPointerException`.